# How can I skip the login in cucumber scenarios to make test fasters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara, selenium-webdriver

I have a rails-app and I'm trying making my cucumber/capybara/selenium-webdriver tests faster. Most of my scenarios look like:

```
@javascript
Feature: Writing reports
  In order .....

  Background:
  Given I am logged in

  Scenario: Scenario 1
    ...........
  Scenario: Scenario 2
    ...........
```

Most of the time is spent in "Given I am logged in" where I go to the sign-up-page to create an user and log in. The authentication is implemented using Devise.

**How can I make that I don't have to do the log-in in the test environment at all?**

**Are there other best practises to get around the tedious log-in-step?** (And only keep the log-in for those scenarios that test the log-in/sign-up specifically)

Comment: Does your config/initializers/devise.rb already have `config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 10` ?

Comment: Thanks. Yes it does. Since it seems that nobody has a problem with the login-steps, I profiled the app and I found a problem. It's much faster now. But I still wonder if there is really no way to get around the login at all?

Comment: No, not in full-stack tests like Capybara and Cucumber.

Answer (score 3):

**Your cucumber scenarios are your living and breathing documentation.** If you need to be logged in to use that part of the app then your cucumber steps should explicitly say so.

As for what you're calling under the hood in Capybara. You could look at the devise session controller and use the same method calls directly in your integration tests. However, if Devise changes it's implementation, your integration tests will break. **Where possible your integration tests should not be concerned with any underlying implementation details.**

The easiest code to maintain, and the most reliable test, will be to fill out the form as the user will.

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of UI deails in your scenarios. This makes it hard to understand which behaviour you really are verifying.

The scenario names gives some hints, but the concrete example in the Given/When/Then contains a lot of details that obfuscates the purpose.

```
Scenario: Login with invalid username/password
  Given I am signed out
  When I log in with invalid user credentials
  Then should I get an error message

Scenario: Login with valid username/password and valid PIN
  Given I am signed out
  When I log in with valid credentials
  then should I be greeted
```

These two examples does not contain any details about a link or pin form. I see those as implementation details that I would push down in the stack. I would push them to a helper class that the steps are using. You seem to be verifying a web application, I would let these details live in a page object that supports the steps.

I would also consider removing the usage of the personal pronome `I` and change that to a persona instead. A persona that is a typical for a user of your system. The persona has a name. Say that we create a persona called 'Ann' who is a 35 year old woman working at the administration department. This would give me the opportunity to rewrite the scenarios to

```
Scenario: Login with invalid username/password
  Given Ann am signed out
  When Ann log in with invalid user credentials
  Then will she receive an error message

Scenario: Login with valid username/password and valid PIN
  Given Ann am signed out
  When Ann log in with valid credentials
  then should Ann be greeted
```

This give us some context, we know who Ann is. We  can keep her user name and password in our supporting classes and expect the implementation to use them properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Warden (which Devise runs on), might check out http://blog.crowdint.com/2012/11/02/using-warden-to-login-logout-within-your-cucumber-tests.html.

The author proposes a method to use Warden helpers instead of filling out the form. Basically logging in with pure Ruby instead of through the browser. For scenarios specifically testing login/logout functionality, you would still test filling in the individual fields, but this might speed up your other cases.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't sign the user up. Just `User.create!` as a part of the Given step. And only sign them in via web UI.
2. Avoid `@javascript` where possible. This way you can utilze devise test helper `sign_in` rather than going via web UI.
3. Use faster javascript driver. For example, as of this writing, [poltergeist](https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist) runs about twice as fast as Firefox on my machine.